# Browser ram memory limit

Tags: browser, three.js, webbrowser-control, webgl, ram

I have a task, which uses a lot of size of ram memory, after that, browser crashes..
I use CANVAS, load a big model, and after that browser crashes.

Is there any way to limit browser process's memory, or change browser's limit and not crash it?
I have to load this model in canvas, but cant do cause of this problem..
Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: I would first look how to handle large data with webgl, for example how point clouds do it: http://potree.org/

Comment: There's no way to change the limit. You're going to have to find other creative solutions. Make your data smaller, swap stuff in and out of memory, etc... Even native app have to do this when the data gets large.